# How to define the min size of array in the json schema

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I want to make a schema of json file.It's for an array of products.

The json schema is similar as below:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Product set",
"type": "array",
"items": {
    "title": "Product",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0,
            "exclusiveMinimum": true
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "dimensions": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "length": {"type": "number"},
                "width": {"type": "number"},
                "height": {"type": "number"}
            },
            "required": ["length", "width", "height"]
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "description": "Coordinates of the warehouse with the product",
            "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/geo"
        }
    },
    "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
}
```

The array should at least one item in it. How can I define the minimum of the array?

Do I need to add the minimun defination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose no, at least looking to working draft the `minimum` is applied only for numeric values, not arrays.

> 5.1.  Validation keywords for numeric instances (number and integer)
> ...
> [5.1.3.  minimum and exclusiveMinimum](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.1.3)

So you should be good with min/maxItems for arrays.

Answer (score 105):

To set the minimum # of item in an array, use the `"minItems"`.

See:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.3.3

and

http://jsonary.com/documentation/json-schema/?section=keywords/Array%20validation

```
   {
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      ...
      "tags": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 1,
          "maxItems": 4,
          "uniqueItems": true
      }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
  }
```

Comment: an example is more useful than links (which may rot over time)

Comment: It works as expected: when `"maxItems": 0`, validation fails if length of `"items"` array is a non-zero. Great!

Comment: how can i add minLength / max Length fot every item (String)
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      ...
      "tags": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 25
          },
          "minItems": 1,
          "maxItems": 4,
          "uniqueItems": true
      }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
  }

Comment: You can add a defintion for the string that look like this (this one has a pattern for the size): "definitions" : {
    "Id": {
      "description" : "CktID description, can have a size 0 if used as end of list",
      "type":"string",
      "pattern" : "^([\u0020-\u007f]){0,28}$"
    },

Answer (score 12):

It looks like draft v4 permits what you are looking for.  From http://json-schema.org/example1.html:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Product",
"description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    ...
    "tags": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "minItems": 1,
        "uniqueItems": true
    }
},
"required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
```

Notice that the "tags" property is defined as an array, with a minimum number of items (1).