# JSON Schema: How to validate an array that must have one or more keys?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to use JSON Schema validation to ensure that my array `favoriteVegetables` includes at least one value from my vegetables enum (`carrot`, `lettuce`, `cucumber`).

The array can have any and all of these values, but it must have at least one value.

Here's my schema:

```
{
  "$id": "https://www.example.com/vegetables.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Vegetables",
  "required": [ "favoriteVegetables" ],
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "favoriteVegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": ["carrot", "lettuce", "cucumber"]
      }
    },
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

The problem is that this validates for an object where `favoriteVegetables` is `[]`.  How do I add the requirement "must have at least one value" (cannot be a null array)?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to define the min size of array in the JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583485/how-to-define-the-min-size-of-array-in-the-json-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `"minItems": 1` keyword.

Reference: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#name-minitems